# fetch-mock with jasmine not triggering then

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jest-fetch-mock

I have this constant:

```
export const clientData = fetch(`${process.env.SERVER_HOST}clientData.json`)
    .then(response => response.json());
```

Which works properly, and Now I'm working on the test of this, with Jasmine and fetch-mock

This is my test:

```
import { clientData } from '../../../src/js/services/client-data.fetch';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

describe('test', () => {
    const exampleResponse = {
        clientData: 'test'
    };

    beforeAll(() => {
        fetchMock.mock('*', exampleResponse);
    });

    it('ooo', () => {
        console.log('here', clientData);
        var a = clientData;
        a.then(b=> console.log(b))
    });
});
```

The console.log of `clientData` returns a `Promise` (Which is fine), but the `then` is never triggered.

Not seeing why, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the test execution is synchronous in nature and it doesn't wait for the assertion to happen, so you have to pass a `done` callback and call it from your test inside the `then` callback

Like this:

```
import { clientData } from '../../../src/js/services/client-data.fetch';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

describe('test', () => {
    const exampleResponse = {
        clientData: 'test'
    };

    beforeAll(() => {
        fetchMock.mock('*', exampleResponse);
    });

    it('ooo', (done) => {
        console.log('here', clientData);
        var a = clientData;
        a.then(b=> {
            console.log(b);
            done();
        })
    });
});
```